# The best and easy way to play music from my Android phone on my Ubuntu laptop

Tags: networking, android, music, mpd

I use Ubuntu 22.10 GNOME and the latest Android on my Samsung A7 2018. I mostly download music files on my Android phone, (from my friends, Telegram channels, etc.) and I mostly play music on my laptop. Is there any way in Ubuntu to skip copying all the time from my phone to my laptop? Most previous questions and available tools act the in the opposite direction.

I am not looking for a tool to access my files on Android in my Nautilus (Wow! that would be also great, is there any way?), I want to play my mobile music directly on an Ubuntu music player such as Rhythmbox, Audacious, etc.

Comment: I see no problem doing that. If you allow file sharing in Android, you can see your files on your phone in Nautilus and play music. It is unclear how you copy files if you don't know that you can see it in Nautilus.

Comment: @Pilot6 I copy them using the cable but I want to access and play the remotely (phone and laptops are on the same WiFi)

Comment: You can play using the same cable. Also you can install an app to Android that will share files using sftp, samba, etc. It is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: I don`t want to use the cable. I want to use them remotely. thank you I will search for the sftp solution

Comment: You might be looking for KDE Connect. See https://kdeconnect.kde.org/ and https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-kde-connect-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/